# search array in array and return key

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have two arrays

1.$ids;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2427975642
    [1] => 2397521678
)
```

2.$c

```
Array
(
    [48] => 2397521678
    [46] => 461
    [45] => 451
)
```

Question:
Search values from $ids in $c and return new array with id. Example return 48

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's really hard to see what you are asking.

Comment: Are you trying to combine/merge the two arrays by their values? And the latter keys should overwrite the former ones?

Comment: Merge eliminated because the resulting table is entry identifiers in the database to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = array(   
    2427975642,
    2397521678
);



$c = array(
    48 => 2397521678,
    46 => 461,
    45 => 451
);

$common = array_keys(array_intersect($c, $ids));

print_r($common);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the function array_intersect: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ids= array
    (
        [0] => 2427975642
        [1] => 2397521678
    );

    $c =array
    (
        [48] => 2397521678
        [46] => 461
        [45] => 451
    );

$res = array_intersect($ids,$c);
$keys = array_keys($res);
print_r($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array(   
    2427975642,
    2397521678
);



$c = array(
    48 => 2397521678,
    46 => 461,
    45 => 451
);

$finalArray = array();

foreach ( $c as $key=>$val)
{

if ( array_search($val,$ids))
{

$finalArray[]=$key;

}

}
```

Comment: $results = array();
foreach($ids as $val)
  foreach($c as $key=>$val2)
    if($val == $val2) array_push($results, $key);
    // or to get just the first, 
    // replace the if statement with 
    //
    // if($val == $val2) { 
    //   $result = $key;
    //   break 2; 
    // }

print_array($results);